# Firebase print snapshot works fine and fetches the dictionary but when tried to access individual field data, returns nil for certain fields

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem accessing values from certain fields in my firebase database. Right now this is how my structure looks in firebase:

```
messages:
 messageId:
    fromId:
    text:
    timestamp:
    toId:
```

I am able to successfully upload the data to firebase when a user inputs a message to another user. And I am also able to successfully print the snapshot. But when I set the dictionary values and access it, only "fromId" and "toId" works but "timestamp" and "text" returns a nil value.

Pretty sure there is some sort of a wrong implementation in terms of taking the snapshot values and setting it. For your reference, I have included 3 files, one where the data model is defined, one where I upload data to firebase and one where I am trying to print it but I get nil.

The file where I am trying to print data but I get nil. Note: I am only getting nil when I am trying to print "text" and "timestamp" field values. "fromId" and "toId" works.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class MessagesController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        observeMessages()
    }

    var messages = [Message]()

    func observeMessages(){
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("messages")
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? 
Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                let message = Message(dictionary: dictionary)
                print(message.text)
        print(message.fromId)
        print(message.toId)
        print(timestamp)
           }
        })
    }
}
```

This is how I am uploading the data to firebase using a handle send function once the user has entered some text in the text box

```
    @objc func handleSend(){
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("messages")
        let childRef = ref.childByAutoId()
        let toId = user!.uid!
        let fromId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let timestamp: Int = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
        let values = ["fromId": fromId, "text": 
inputTextField.text!, "timestamp": timestamp, "toId": toId] as 
[String : Any]
        childRef.updateChildValues(values)
    }
```

Finally this is how I have declared my messages class:

```
class Message{
    var fromId: String!
    var text: String!
    var timestamp: Int!
    var toId: String!
    init(dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        if let text = dictionary["messageText"] as? String {
            self.text = text
        }

        if let fromId = dictionary["fromId"] as? String {
            self.fromId = fromId
        }

        if let toId = dictionary["toId"] as? String {
            self.toId = toId
        }

        if let timestamp = dictionary["creationDate"] as? Int {
            self.timestamp = timestamp
        }
    }
}
```

When I print message.fromID, I get the data results in the console but when I print message.text or message.timestamp I get 
nil
nil
nil

So in summary snapshot works, fromId, toID fields also work but for some reason the data from the text and timestamp fields are returned as nil

Comment: Note: Snapshot also successfully shows the data in all the fields so I am guessing a mistake in declaring the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your are accessing values from dictionary with invalid key use text instead of messageText and use timeSamp instead of creationDate.  like below

```
class Message{
    var fromId: String!
    var text: String!
    var timestamp: Int!
    var toId: String!
    init(dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        if let text = dictionary["text"] as? String {
            self.text = text
        }

        if let fromId = dictionary["fromId"] as? String {
            self.fromId = fromId
        }

        if let toId = dictionary["toId"] as? String {
            self.toId = toId
        }

        if let timestamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as? Int {
            self.timestamp = timestamp
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lol that's like the silliest mistake I can ever make. Been stuck on this for ages and didn't notice this. You're a life saver man

Comment: sometimes its painful :p